# C/C++ assistance with working with multiple files in C

Tags: c++, c

I have a project that has 3 files. File A is main.cpp, while the other two contain a function each (file B contains FOO(), File C contains FOO(int, double)).  What I would like to do is link the 3 files so main() in File A  can call FOO() in File B), which in should call FOO(int, double) in file C.

Note: I am not working with any particular header files in my C program here.

Comment: *"Note: I am not working with any particular header files in my C program here."* - Why is that exactly?

Comment: because my goal is not to learn how to do it perfectly, but to learn the rules that really apply here.

Answer (score 3):

C.h:

```
FOO(int, double);
```

B.h:

```
#include "C.h"    
FOO();
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "B.h"
```

commands to compile:

```
g++ -I. -c main.cpp
g++ -c B.cpp C.cpp
g++ -o final_executable main.o B.o C.o
```

Basically, you first provide *prototypes* for the functions you wish to call. You then compile B, C, and main (but don't link any of them) - the `-c` argument inhibits linking. This creates *object files*. Finally, you *link* all three object files together into an executable.

Comment: the OP needs to learn more about a compiler. +1

Comment: Note that compilation could be simply done by a single call to g++ like `g+ main.cpp B.cpp C.cpp -o final_executable`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: main.cpp includes b.h, b.cpp includes c.h?

Comment: @SRK Yes, corrected. zxcdw, I don't recommend teaching that way, because it ceases to be possible to do compilation and linking together with larger projects. So it's generally better to acquire improved understanding and adopt better practices at the beginning, no?

Comment: I don't have any header files. I am simply working with .cpp files though. What are the rules for this scenario? Note I have seen program samples that specify includes for .c/.cc c/.cpp files(I am reading the book The C Compendium) and trying to run the examples from the book.

Comment: @user272671 If you don't want to *create* header files (which is what you should do), you can put `FOO(int, double);` into `B.cpp` and `main.cpp`, and `FOO();` into `main.cpp` (before the site of each function's use).

Comment: I think what I am trying to find out is how I can use FILE SCOPE to my advantage here. Since all functions defined at file scope are by default extern, should I not then be able to hook up all my .C files and not have to use header files?

Comment: @user272671 You've misunderstood. You **can** call the functions from other files, but you have to tell the compiler what the function is - its *prototype*. A prototype looks like `void FOO(int, double)`. You need to have one for each externally-defined function you wish to call before the site of its first call.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get away of defining an interface when you want "independent" components of software to interact with each other. In this case, you have decided to define components `main.cpp`, `B.cpp` and `C.cpp`. For `main()` to call `FOO()` in `B.cpp`, the C++ language type rules require that a prototype exists first. This serves at least two useful purposes. It allows the compiler to statically check that functions are passed the correct arguments during compile time. It also provides the compiler enough information to manage function arguments efficiently (e.g., stack vs. register). Most of the time, interfaces are defined in a header file, so it should feel natural to use them.

Sometimes, software is developed using a dynamic interface. In this case, what function is to be called is determined at runtime. The `dlopen`, `dlsym`, and `dlclose` calls can be used to achieve this. A simple example might be:

```
// main.cpp
int main () {
    void *dh = dlopen(0, RTLD_LAZY);
    void (*B_FOO_PTR)(void)
        = *static_cast<void (**)(void)>(dlsym(dh, "B_FOO_PTR"));
    dlcose(dh);
    B_FOO_PTR();
}
```

---

```
// B.cpp
static void FOO () {
    void *dh = dlopen(0, RTLD_LAZY);
    void (*C_FOO_PTR)(int, double)
        = *static_cast<void (**)(int, double)>(dlsym(dh, "C_FOO_PTR"));
    dlcose(dh);
    C_FOO_PTR(0, 1.0);
}

extern "C" { void (*B_FOO_PTR)(void) = &FOO; }
```

---

```
// C.cpp
static void FOO (int, double) {
    //...
}

extern "C" { void (*C_FOO_PTR)(int, double) = &FOO; }
```